# JS text editor control with flexible dynamic visual styling capabilities

Tags: javascript, text-editor

I'm looking for a JS text editor control for any sane framework, that would allow me to color and otherwise style text in run-time as user types it in a custom markdownesque format.

Note that the actual format is quite different from Markdown, so I can't simply reuse some existing Markdown editor. Also, the purpose of this stuff is to help user with semi-structured data input, not fancy text formatting by itself.

In addition to styling text, I would like to be able to dynamically insert UI elements (say, buttons) in the text, again, depending on what user typed in.

I must also be able to send changes to the server-side in background, in some more-or-less effective way. I think that I would need to write some custom callbacks there anyway, but it would be cool if a control would provide a comfortable framework for that (or at least if it would not stand in my way).

Support for the usual features like undo/redo and copy/paste is, of course, a must.

A silly synthetic example to clarify what rules I want to be able to code:

The text:

```
-- Foo

    Bar {green}
    *Baz*

-- Alpha {red}
```

Styles:

- From line with `Foo` to line before `Alpha`: background color is green.
- Line with `Alpha`: red background
- Word `*Baz*` (along with asterisks) is in bold.
- Next to words `Foo` and `Alpha`: buttons with a trash can image, if pressed delete whole section of text from current `--` to the next one.
- When user presses <kbd>Return</kbd> on line with `--`, cursor position on the next line is auto-indented.
- If user types `--` at the beginning of (indented) line, new section is started and line is unindented. (Actual indentation characters /spaces/ must appear in the text.)

Note that I want these visual styles to be applied *in the editor* as user types. If, in the example, user changes `{green}` to `{blue}`, background color should be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Yahoo Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/). It's open source.

Comment: It seems to be a bit complicated (but, then, editors usually are). Is there a good example for me to build upon?

Comment: Re: examples? See the examples list on the right side of the web page.

Comment: I saw them, of course, but did not find an example that would help me to code what I need (as described in the question text). Maybe I missed something?